# Range such that $g(\alpha)$=100

Tags: calculus, contest-math

This is a problem which I am having a really hard time solving this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Also sorry for my poor English.

> For some real number $0<\alpha<\pi$, $a_n$ is defined as 
> $$a_n=(2n-1)\alpha$$
> There exists a function $f(x)$, being differentiable in all real number and such that f(0)=0. $f'(x)$ is given as this.
> $$f'(x) = \begin{cases}\cos x & x < a_1 \\ cos(x-2n\alpha) & a_n\leq x<a_{n+1}\end{cases}$$
> Let $g(\alpha)$ be function of the number of positive roots of $f(x)=1$. The range of $\alpha$ such that $g(\alpha)=100$ is $m<\alpha<n$. Find the value of $\frac{\sin m}{\sin n}.$

I am aware that the integration constant is different for each n and have so far integrated $f(x)$ and tried to graph it, but it didn't go well...Any hints or solutions please?

Comment: Presumably either the domain of $f$ is restricted to $x \ge 0$, or else $g(\alpha)$ is the number of *positive* roots of $f(x) = 1$. Because for $x < 0, f(x) = \sin x$ which has infinitely many roots of $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Oh sorry I’ll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)$ just repeats the graph of $\cos x$ from $-\alpha$ to $\alpha$ periodically with a period of $2\alpha$. Because $\cos(-\alpha) = \cos \alpha, f'(x)$ is continuous. If $\alpha \le \frac \pi2$, then $f'\ge 0$ everywhere and only $= 0$ at isolated points, so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, and $f(x) = 1$ would have only one root.

Conversely, if $\alpha$ were allowed to be $\pi$, then $f'(x) = \cos x$ everywhere, and because the area between the $x$-axis and $\cos x$ is the same below the axis as above, integrating $\cos x$ keeps adding and removing the same amount of area, which is why the integral $\sin x$ is also periodic. However, for lower values of $\alpha > \frac \pi2$, some portion of the cosine curve *below* the $x$-axis is removed, while the portion above the axis remains, so when integrating, with each repetition of the period, more positive area is added than negative area, with the result that $f(x)$ will have an overall upward trend. But since $f'(x)$ is periodic with period $2\alpha$, integrating it over an interval of width $2\alpha$ will pick up the same area every time. So there is some constant $A$ such that $f(x + 2\alpha) = f(x) + A$ for all $x$ (like $f, A$ depends on $\alpha$ but not $x$).

Note also that for $\alpha > \frac \pi2$ that we know exactly where the local minima and maxima of $f$ occur. The minima occur at $-\frac\pi2 + 2k\alpha$, while the maxima occur at $\frac\pi2 + 2k\alpha$ for $k \in \Bbb N$.

Put those last two facts together (in particular, figure out what $A$ is), and the solution should be in sight.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I'll look at it again!